# Why does printf implicit float to int conversion not work?

Tags: c, printf

Please help me in understanding the following C Output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    float x = 4.0;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    int y=x;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput on gcc compiler

```
4.000000
0
4
```

As far as i have read when we assign float to an int variable the decimal part of the variable is terminated and then assigned to the int.

Why it is not happening in this case?

Comment: Do you mean to output `x` in the last print statement?

Comment: Last `printf` prints `x` again, not `y`.

Comment: thnx all...i'm have asked a silly question...and a blunder in the code....i meant to print y in the last statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why cast is needed in printf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303673/why-cast-is-needed-in-printf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not printing `y`, you're printing `x` again.

As a side note, **`printf` can't do conversions**. So passing a float when a `%d` is expected is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> as far as i have read when we assign float to an int variable the
>   decimal part of the variable is terminated and then assigned to the
>   int.

Statement is correct, but to make this conversion you must **`cast`** variable you wish to convert, not just assign it to another int variable.

This causes problems also in the `printf` statement, since you are printing a float variable with int specifier `%d` without a cast.

Fix you're code like this:

```
printf("%d\n", (int) x);
                 ^
                 | this is the cast operation
```

and it will correctly print integer value `4` for variable `x`.

Answer (score 1):

`floats` are automatically promoted to `doubles` when passed as `...` parameters (similarly to how `chars` and `short ints` are promoted to `ints`). When `printf()` looks at a format specifier (`%d` or `%f` or whatever), it grabs and interprets the raw data it has received according to the format specifier (as `int` or `double` or whatever) and then prints it.

`printf("%d\n",x)` is wrong because you are passing a `double` to `printf()` but lie to it that it's going to be an `int`. `printf()` makes you pay for the lie. It takes 4 bytes (most likely, but not necessarily 4 bytes) from its parameters, which is the size of an `int`, it grabs those bytes from where you have previously put 8 bytes (again, most likely, but not necessarily 8 bytes) of the `double` 4.0, of which those 4 bytes happen to be all zeroes and then it interprets them as an integer and prints it. Indeed, powers of 2 in the IEEE-754 double precision format normally have 52 zero bits, or more than 6 8-bit bytes that are zero.

Those "most likely, but not necessarily" words mean that the C standard does not mandate a fixed size and range for types and they may vary from compiler to compiler, from OS to OS. These days 4-byte `ints` and 8-byte `doubles` are the most common (if we consider, e.g. the x86 platform).

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between cast and conversion ?