# Why does this output of the same expression from printf differ from cout?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, printf, cout

I'm using Visual C++ 2012 and compiling from the command line the following files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%.5f", 18/4+18%4);
    return 0;
}
```

Linking with MSVCRT.LIB rather than LIBCMT to avoid runtime error R6002.
The value that is output is 0.00000 for this program.

However, if I perform the exact same thing in C++

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
 {
      cout << 18/4+18%4 << endl;
      return 0;
 }
```

Now, it prints out 6, like it should.

What's the difference? Is it to do with the languages themselves (C vs C++) or the output methods (cout vs printf), or is it just a quirk with MSVC?

Comment: Try with `"%d"` instead of `"%.5f"`.

Comment: Seems as if your first code example printf format expects a float, but the arithmetic is integer arithmetic.

Comment: your first example is purely integer arithmetic, the compiler properly compiled your code

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559198/.

Comment: By the way, they didn't remove `printf` from C++ so you could have tried it there and seen immediately where the problem was.

Comment: a nice demonstration of why strongly typed cout is better than loosy goosy printf

Comment: Also note as I stated in my answer this use of `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @pm100 I would have interpreted it as strongly typed printf format strings catching an error and cout silently making it work! :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually `%f` is `double`, in variadic functions floats are promoted to double.

Comment: @congusbongus - the printf code compiled and did the wrong thing , not what the dev intended and in fact invoked undefined behavior. cout did exactly what the dev expected

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The expression `18/4+18%4` evaluates to an `int`, and you are requesting a float. You should always compile with warnings enabled, and pay attention to them (they say *a warning is a bug waiting to happen*, and they are right).

This is what my compiler (GCC 4.8.1) tells me (and even without enforcing `-Wall`):

```
warning: format ‘%.5f’ expects type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

On the other hand, the `std::cout<<` operation is able to deduce the type of your expression and correctly stream it to your screen.

Comment: The type of `18/4+18%4` is `int`, not "integer".

Comment: The `%.5f` format expects a `double`, not a `float`. (`float` arguments to `printf` are promoted to `double` but that's not relevant in this case.)

Comment: Tiny correction - don't pay attention to warnings. Use `-Werror` so they'll stop your compilation.

Answer (score 37):

The C function is being passed an integer, but you are telling it (with `%f`) to expect a double-precision floating point number, so it fails. The C++ function knows that it is being passed an integer, so it works properly.

Comment: The `printf` didn't fail (go kaboom). It just didn't work as expected.

Comment: @DavidHammen: It certainly failed to work *properly*, but just because it prints 0 for him doesn't mean it will print 0 for everybody. For some people, it could go kaboom.

Comment: C11dr 7.21.6.1 9 "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @chux: Indeed, "kaboom" is actually one of the allowable outcomes! :)

Answer (score 12):

In the *C* example this expression `18/4+18%4` will evaluate to an *int* since all the operands are *integer constants* but you are specifying that it is a *double* to `printf` and therefore it is will be processed incorrectly. On the other hand if you had used a *Floating constant* in the division part of the expression for example `18.0/4+18%4` the whole expression would have evaluated to a *double*. Alternatively you could have used `"%d"` in the format specifier as well.

This is also [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) to incorrectly specify the format to `printf` and this also demonstrates why building with warnings is important, using `gcc -Wall` I receive the following warning(*see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d53a174ee99c094f)*):

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’
```

In *C++* [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)'s [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) has an overload for `int` and therefore that will be called in this case. We can see this overload an many others are required by the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), in section `27.7.3.1` *Class template basic_ostream* we find the following operator declaration:

```
basic_ostream<charT,traits>& operator<<(int n);
```

For completeness sake, circling back to the undefined behavior, the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function* which `printf`'s section refers back to for the format string paragraph *9* says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.[...]

Comment: Apparently `gcc` and `clang` warn for this regardless of warning settings, which is good but this does not change the fact that having warning enabled will prevent many bugs.

Answer (score 11):

The expression

```
18 / 4 + 18 % 4
```

evaluates to an *int*.

But the *printf* format string *"%.5f"* expects a double.

With c++ and ostreams, the language can determine the output type automatically.

Just change your C-code to following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("%d", 18 / 4 + 18 % 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Others have correctly pointed out the int/double mismatch in your printf() statement.  I just want to comment on your statement, "Linking with MSVCRT.LIB rather than LIBCMT to avoid runtime error R6002."  A program this simple should not unduly tax the runtime environment, so a runtime error like this should be a red flag of undefined behavior in your code.

A quick Google of "MSVCRT R6002" says:

> **C Run-Time Error R6002**
>   *floating-point support not loaded*
>
> The necessary floating-point library was not linked.
>   To fix by checking the following possible causes
>
> 1. The program was compiled or linked with an option, such as /FPi87, that requires a coprocessor, but the program was run on a machine that did not have a coprocessor installed.
> 2. **A format string for a printf_s or scanf_s function contained a floating-point format specification and the program did not contain any floating-point values or variables.**
> 3. **The compiler minimizes a program's size by loading floating-point support only when necessary. The compiler cannot detect floating-point format specifications in format strings, so it does not load the necessary floating-point routines.**
> 4. Use a floating-point argument to correspond to the floating-point format specification, or perform a floating-point assignment elsewhere in the program. This causes floating-point support to be loaded.
> 5. In a mixed-language program, a C library was specified before a FORTRAN library when the program was linked. Relink and specify the C library last.

The lesson here, of course, is that you should pay close attention to compiler and runtime warnings & errors.  When in doubt, always assume the problem is in your code, not in the compiler's.

Comment: I just figured linking to a library that had floating point support built in (MSVCRT does) then it'd solve the problem.  I understand the mistake now, though.

Answer (score 4):

In C because you explicitly specify floating point ("%f") in your printf format specifier, so it's expecting a floating point argument.  But you're giving it an "int" argument, hence the problem.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you can:

1) Casting your (otherwise *integer*) expression to float

and/or

2) Using [setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) in your cout stream, just as you'd use "%.5f" in C:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   float x = 18/4+18%4;
   std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << x << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

3) If you *want* integer, use `printf ("%d", 18/4+18%4);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want the same behaviour (and response) you'd better to code

```
printf("%d\n", 18/4 + 18%4);
```

to get an int response instead of a floating point one.  You'll get the same result as `<<` operator selected is

`ostream& std::operator<<(ostream&, const int);`

Otherwise, you can use explicitly

```
printf("%.5f\n", (double)(18/4 + 18%4));
```

to get `6.00000` result.

Answer (score 1):

Have one of your numbers be a floating point value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    printf("%.0f", 18/4.0+18%4);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible alternative is, typecasting the literals (or the expression itself):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%.5f", (float)18/4+18%4);
    return 0;
}
```