# C - Calculating and printing int as float

Tags: c

I'm writing a `switch` statement and trying to print `f` as a float. In this context `a` is 40 and `b` is 400, so I need to print out 0.1

My question is, since `f` is an `int`, how can I go about this? I've already tried using `%f` instead of `%d` and I've also cast `a` as a `float`. But every time it just prints 0.00000000

```
case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
```

Just to clarify all three values are ints.

Comment: why storing a float value in an int? it will be converted to int

Comment: `a`,`b` are `int` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this output of the same expression from printf differ from cout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102778/why-does-this-output-of-the-same-expression-from-printf-differ-from-cout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `f` to store a `float` value, you need to declare it as a `float`.  You also need to cast either `a` or `b` to `float` for the result of the division to be a `float`.

Then you can use the `%f` format specifier to print it.

```
float f;
...
case '/': f = (float)a / b; printf("f = %f\n", f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cast the result of the division to `float` before storing to your `f` variable:

```
case '/': f = (float) a / b; printf("f = %.2f\n", f);
```

You can also use `%n.nf` to print the number of decimals you want to. In the above example 2 decimals.

Another example code:

```
float f;
int a = 5;
int b = 3;

f = (float) a/b;

printf ("%2.2f\n", f);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot store a float value in an integer one because the decimal part will be discarded, converted implicitly to an integer so you have to declare f as float or double or float:

```
float f;
int a(40), b(400);
f = (float)a / (float)b;
printf("%g", f);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%f` format specifier will not magically convert the result of integer division to a floating point number for you, nor will it treat an `int` as a `float` or `double`.  You need to declare `f` as a `float` yourself, and ensure that the operation `a / b` is not treated as integer division:

```
float f;
...

case '/': 
    f = (float)a / (float)b;
    printf("f = %f\n", f);
```